Problems with using forms and sections in Xcode
This is not working the 'Section' and 'Form' show errors:

Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure

There is a problem with using forms and sections in my xcode and i cannot pinpoint the problem, even the most basic form with a simple section gives errors:

Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Section' conform to 'View'


Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Decoder' that does not accept a closure

import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth

struct SettingsView: View {
@State private var notificationsEnabled: Bool = false
@State private var locationEnabled: Bool = false
@State private var darkModeEnabled: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        Form {
            
            // Preferences Section
            Section(header: Text("Preferences")) {
                Toggle("Enable Notifications", isOn: $notificationsEnabled)
                Toggle("Enable Location Services", isOn: $locationEnabled)
                Toggle("Enable Dark Mode", isOn: $darkModeEnabled)
            }

            // Other Settings Section
            Section(header: Text("Terms & Policy")) {
                NavigationLink(destination: PrivacyPolicyView()) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Privacy Policy")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: TermsOfServiceView()) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Terms of Service")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            // User Account Section
            Section(header: Text("Account")) {
                Button(action: logout) {
                    Text("Logout")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                Button(action: deleteAccount) {
                    Text("Delete Account")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
    }
}

func logout() {
    // Implement logout functionality here
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        print("User logged out")
    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
        print("Error signing out: \(signOutError)")
    }
}

func deleteAccount() {
    // Implement delete account functionality here
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    user?.delete { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error deleting account: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("User account deleted")
        }
    }
}
}

struct PrivacyPolicyView: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("Privacy Policy")
        .navigationTitle("Privacy Policy")
}
}

struct TermsOfServiceView: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("Terms of Service")
        .navigationTitle("Terms of Service")
}
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    SettingsView()
}
}


Could not replicate your error, the code compiles and runs well in my tests (commenting FirebaseAuth).
Note, NavigationView is deprecated use NavigationStack instead.
On what line do you get the error?

Hello, thank you for your reply. It fails in "Section" lines...

works well for me, no errors. What system are you using/targeting?
